# Only keep string following a certain pattern in complex strings with text and numbers in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a huge set of data with thousands of columns, one of the column I need to extract certain string patterns: e.g. 41242456-2020-12 or 41242456-2020-2 or 41242456-2020-200 (8 digit number-year-1~3 digit number), that was mixed among text in the string, e.g. most of times the numbers appear in the beginning, sometimes its like the following:

Blah Blah LEX#41242456-2020-12BLABLABLAH

Blah Blah LEXIDA ID:41242456-2020-12BLAHBLAHBLAH etc.

Hence unable to extract them fully through one formula.

Is there a way I can use any formula/vba code to only extract 41242456-2020-12 and removing all other characters?

Comment: Will the char `-` be present only in the pattern? Will the year number be always the same one (ie 2020 now because we are in 2020, next year 2021, and so on)? But probably you could use here regex or split

Comment: What is the potential range of years?  Excel's allowable range is `1900`-`9999`, but perhaps you have a different possible range.

Comment: yes, it will only in the pattern, Regex is new to me, I will definitely try it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/regex/) and elsewhere on the web on how to use regular expressions in Excel.

The regular expression you want to match against is `\d{8}-[12]\d{3}-\d{1,3}` which means

1. eight numbers
2. a dash
3. a "1" or a "2" (because if it's 3, or 0 then I assume it's not a valid year)
4. three numbers
5. a dash
6. one to three numbers

[image: Notepad testing of regular expression]

You might want to use `(\d{8})-([12]\d{3})-(\d{1,3})` so that matching will give you the three numbers for you. Parentheses in regular expressions mean 'return what matched this part.'